# Rearrange View Layer order for organizational purposes?

Tags: interface, viewlayers

Is there a way to rearrange View Layers without having to make copies + delete the original (to effectively bump it to the bottom of the list)? For example, if I wanted to move the 'View All' layer to the top of the list, is there a way to do that?

[image: view layers]

Comment: AFAIK it can't be done out of the box. There used to be [this addon](https://github.com/RayMairlot/Move-Render-Layers) used to do it back in Blender v2.78 but it hasn't been updated yet. So either someone updates it, or someone makes a new similar addon for modern Blender.